# org.apache.httpd: Already loaded

Tags: macos, apache

I have this weird issue with apache:

```
$ apachectl configtest

Syntax OK
```

Configs are ok, and it was actually working a minute ago, before I shut it down.

```
$ sudo apachectl start
org.apache.httpd: Already loaded
```

No it's not:

```
$ ps ax | grep httpd
58204 s000  R+     0:00.00 grep httpd
```

Let's try to stop it:

```
$ sudo apachectl stop
```

Looks like it is stopped, right? Let's try to start it again:

```
$ sudo apachectl start
$ sudo apachectl start
org.apache.httpd: Already loaded
```

So it must be running but it's not in `ps ax` and it simply doesn't work.

```
$ sudo apachectl stop
$ sudo apachectl stop
launchctl: Error unloading: org.apache.httpd
```

Tried to remove it from autostart:

```
$ sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist
$ sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist
launchctl: Error unloading: org.apache.httpd
```

But it's the same when I try to launch it, it pretends that it starts but it doesn't. Nothing in error log either. Help!

OS X 10.8.2 Mountain Lion

**Update:**

After reboot:

```
$ sudo apachectl start
Password:
org.apache.httpd: Already loaded

$ sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist
org.apache.httpd: Already loaded

$ ps ax | grep httpd
7300 s000  R+     0:00.00 grep httpd
```

So I am effectively left without a web-server now.

**Solution:**

After a study of `org.apache.httpd.plist` I figured out that apache is controlled by a ruby script `/usr/sbin/http-wrapper` which had some issues running because I had replaced the system ruby interpreter. This fixed it for me:

```
ln -s /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current/usr/bin/ruby /usr/bin/ruby
```

Comment: After a study of `org.apache.httpd.plist` I figured out that apache is controlled by a ruby script `/usr/sbin/http-wrapper` which had some issues running because I had replaced the system ruby interpreter. This fixed it: `ln -s /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current/usr/bin/ruby /usr/bin/ruby`

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is too localized - the OP had replaced system software which would always be a problem

Answer (score 11):

run the server manually and fix the error reported:

```
root#> /usr/sbin/httpd -k start
```

Answer (score 1):

my fix was toggling-off the "…apache_access_log combined" in httpd.conf.

i was rudely confronted with this same little setback today, though like glasnhos-, w/out ruby wrapper. @glasnhost, your after-thought tipped me off.. early in the day i had tooled around apache httpd.conf, playing with the log. i had toggled-on the second of these two *almost identical* lines (w/ quotes, and w/out quotes; notice one has an extension `.log`; while the other is underscore `_log`).

```
     # CustomLog "/Applications/MAMP/logs/apache_access.log" combined
       CustomLog /Applications/MAMP/logs/apache_access_log combined
```

similarly, and oddly the problem didn't spook my system until hours later. thanks to this thread my system is back and healthy! *no cred to uptick..*

Answer (score 0):

Reading this article and Nick reply at 5th November, I tried to run /usr/sbin/http-wrapper at Terminal as root user. And I received this output

```
titanium:~ root# /usr/sbin/httpd-wrapper
(2)No such file or directory: httpd: could not open error log file /private/var/log/apache2/error_log.
Unable to open logs
titanium:~ root#
```

Then I checked that /private/var/log/apache2 folder doesn't exist. I created it and set rights to everyone.

```
titanium:log root# mkdir /private/var/log/apache2      
titanium:log root# chmod 777 /private/var/log/apache2/
titanium:log root#
```

It works for me!
Note: If you care about security, give a more restricted permission to /private/var/log/apache2 and not 777.